# parse file and date manipulation in bash with a large file

Tags: bash, date, awk, getline

I'm looking for a better way to manipulate a date format into something that I want. I do manage to do it, but I have to process the files several times because I can not get `date` to do it in one pass.

The format I have:
`Wed Jan 30 08:00:00 2019 : misc data`

The format I want:
`30/01/2019 08:00:00 : misc data`

However, I am only able to get `date` to process the date info if it is in the format:
`30-Jan-2019 08:00:00 : misc data`

(note: `misc data` is a long string containing many unwieldy characters)

To achieve what I want I am using:

```
awk '{("date --date="$3"-"$2"-"$5"\\ "$4" +%F") | getline $1;$2="";$3="";$4;$5=""} 1' oldfile | tr -s ' ' > newfile
```

What this does is creates a format I can use, parses that into fields $1, clears fields 2, 3, and 5, prints it out (keeping the time in field 4, and misc data) and strips out the extra spaces left by the blank fields and saves it to a new file. I then I have to manipulate the format including the separators (because `date` doesn't like `/` if using a named month) into a new format and the whole process is becoming too complicated.

I then run another `awk` over it swapping fields and separators around.

I'm sure this can be streamlined but it's starting too confuse me now.

I do realise I should be using the output `format` of `date`, but because there are slashes involved, as soon as I include single or double quotes, or try to escape them, I find that anything involving multiple format elements fails.

To make it worse, this all works when I work on a limited set of data (usually a sample limited by `head` or `tail`, but the original file is some 20,000 entries long and it fails at `FNR=1043` with too many open files. It is only the one file open and one file saved. I think this is as a result of using `getline`. Is there a way to do this without using it??

Comment: I urge you to use date format `YYYY-mm-dd` -- that format is unambiguous, and it sorts the same lexically and chronologically.

Comment: I agree, I am a huge proponent of ISO8601, however I don't control the source files. I am only converting to the aforementioned format to be inline with the next set of files that need to be merged in.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `date` just to shuffle text around:

```
$ echo 'Wed Jan 30 08:00:00 2019 : misc data' |
awk '{
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3
    date = sprintf("%02d/%02d/%04d %s", $3, mthNr, $5, $4)
    sub(/^([^ ]+ +){5}/,"")
    print date, $0
}'
30/01/2019 08:00:00 : misc data
```

The `too many open files` error you got btw is because you aren't closing the pipe after every invocation of getline. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when and how to use getline robustly.

Comment: The power of `awk`. lol. I was trying to avoid a convoluted `index` and thought using `date` would be easier. I understand your month index, and date `sprintf`, but can you explain what is happening on the `sub` line? That is going completely beyond me.

Comment: It's just removing the first 5 fields, i.e. the date+time. Each field is a sequence of non-blanks (`[^ ]+`) and the fields are separated from eahc other by blanks (`<blank>+`) so to match the first 5 fields plus the separator after each is `^([^ ]+ +){5}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
$ echo 'Wed Jan 30 08:00:00 2019 : misc data' | awk -F: -v OFS=: ' { t=$NF;NF--; 
    cmd="date -d\047" $0 "\047 \047+%d/%m/%Y %T\047"; if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) 
    close(cmd); print line,t}'
30/01/2019 08:00:00: misc data
$
```

Comment: That should be `date="N/A"; if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) date=line;
    close(cmd); print date,t` or similar otherwise if getline failed you'd leave the pipe open and quietly print the last value of `line` for which getline succeeded.